# I want allow itextsharp write in Arabic Font

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, pdf-generation, itext

I'm using Itextsharp in Asp.net Application

to create An arabic Texts,DataTables but this code doesn't work

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\\\windows\\\\fonts\\\\tahoma.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
iTextSharp.text.Font FontAr = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(3f,"مرحبا" ,FontAr));
```

It appears reversal chars in texts and doesn't appear at all inside Table Cells,

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15201049/231316 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6130733/231316

Comment: really was helpful .. thanks alot

Comment: I was facing this problem before, you may have a look at my question " Convert arabic"unicode" content html or xml to pdf using itextsharp " that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080741/convert-arabicunicode-content-html-or-xml-to-pdf-using-itextsharp