# Allow Arabic letters on iTextSharpWorker

Tags: vb.net, itext

I have the following code that works fine when exporting regular HTML to PDF. However, Arabic words in the string `strDetails` such as "مرحبا" are not displaying in the exported PDF file. Any help on this?

```vb
strDetails = "SOME HTML CONTENT"
Dim sr As New StringReader(strDetails)
Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
pdfDoc.Open()
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr)
pdfDoc.Close()
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=HTML.pdf")
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
Response.Write(pdfDoc)
Response.End()
```

Comment: Have a look at http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/html-and-right-left-writing-systems

Comment: You do not seem to be using the right font. Once you do, you will probably notice other problems, so please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15197040/11683 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/34528259/11683.